# keras unable to print inside an inbuilt function

Tags: keras, python-3.6

I wanted to use print some data inside Keras Mobilenetv2 model but it seems using print inside it is not detected by the system and I get no output at all for it.

Even though code seems to be traversing through the function I can not print anything from inside of it after calling it. Even if I just insert a `print("hello!")` in the beginning of function's body it is not printed on console when function is run.

Can anyone suggest me possible reasons for it.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which backend you use. But most backends like tensorflow use a two step approach:

1. Build your execution graph
2. Run it

Only the first thing is done in python. So your python code gets only executed once when building your graph. Since a python print function is nothing tensor related, the backend will execute it during compalation but ignore it for the execution path.

If you want to use a print during execution, there are special backend functions for that.
If you have a tensorflow backend you can use [tf.print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print).